# Updating Firebase records that are displayed in an Android ListView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

So far, I have been able to display my Firebase records for node `maintenance` in an Android `ListView`.  However, there is one part of these records that I wish to update.

When clicking on a record, an `AlertDialog` dialog will appear with a spinner (`spinnerProgress`). By changing the option on this `spinner` and clicking an OK 'button', then the `ListView` and of course the Firebase database will update.

*** EDIT ***

So, I have progressed with this problem a bit. When I click my `buttonUpdateProgress`, the part of the `ListView` (`progress`) updates perfectly.

However, along with it, it removes my strings `title` and `description` from the `ListView`.  Any ideas so that it only `progress` changes?

Below is my code:

```
listViewIssues.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Maintenance maintenance = maintenanceList.get(position);

            showProgressDialog(maintenance.getMaintenanceId(), maintenance.getMaintenanceTitle(), maintenance.getMaintenanceDescription(), maintenance.getMaintenanceProperty(), maintenance.getMaintenanceProgress());
        }
    });
```

--

```
private void showProgressDialog(final String id, String title, String description, String property, String maintenanceTitle) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.archive_maintenance, null);

        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final Spinner spinnerProgress = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerProgress);
        final Button buttonUpdateProgress = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateProgress);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Maintenance: " + maintenanceTitle);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        buttonUpdateProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
                String desc = editTextDesc.getText().toString().trim();

                String progress = spinnerProgress.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String property = spinnerProperty.getSelectedItem().toString();

                updateProgress(title, desc, id, property, progress);

                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

--

```
private boolean updateProgress (String title, String desc, String id, String property, String progress) {

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("maintenance").child(id);
        Maintenance maintenance = new Maintenance(id, title, desc, property, progress);

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();

        databaseMaintenance.child(uid).child(id).setValue(maintenance);

        databaseReference.setValue(maintenance);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Maintenance Updated Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: is there any error what are the things remaining

Comment: What is the problem? You didn't mentioned that

Comment: @HemalHerath I have updated the question.

Comment: @DeepPatel I have updated the question.

Comment: @wright_arturo : please check my answer below. added some space and comment for your ease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Can you please try replacing this function with your function and try**

**Some explanation:**

```
ref.updateChildren(hashMap); // will let you update the only data you want to change

ref.setValue(model);  // will replace the existing data with the model you provided
```

**Function to replace**

```
private boolean updateProgress (String title, String desc, String id, String property, String progress) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                           .getReference().child("maintenance");
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

    params.put("progress", progress);  // put only params you want to update

    databaseReference.child(uid)
                     .child(id)
                     .updateChildren(params);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Maintenance Updated Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```

Note: put only params you want to update like in example below, here if you want to change progress only then snippet will be like,

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

params.put("progress", progress); 

ref.updateChildren(params);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Thankfully now the other values (title, desc) don't disappear. But `progress` will now not changed.  LogCat saying that there is a DB error - Permission Denied. Any ideas?

Comment: Please put your full logcat data

Comment: `04-04 11:33:11.233 14691-14743/com.example.xxx.myapplication W/RepoOperation: updateChildren at /maintenance/-L9FPsVynRtOjPg7m9DD failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied`

Comment: This is strange, considering that I was able to get it to change. Albeit at the expense of the `title` and `desc`

Comment: This looks like problem with your google-services.json.

Make sure app name and client id are same as in firebase console.

If you are not sure re-download google-services.json from your project's console and add it your project.

Comment: Update your rules as 

"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
}}

Comment: I am using user-based authentication so I cannot change my rules.  Do I need to put these anywhere?

`ref.updateChildren(hashMap); 
ref.setValue(model);  
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168208/discussion-between-deep-patel-and-wright-arturo).