# Firebase database is updating but Android ListView containing data is not

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have implemented an `spinner` in an `Alert Dialog` with an update button that is successfully updating my Firebase database. This was achieved using help here - [Updating Firebase records that are displayed in an Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648561/updating-firebase-records-that-are-displayed-in-an-android-listview/49649027#49649027)

However, these updates in data are not being reflected in the `ListView` that is displaying the Firebase data, they are just staying the same.

Can anyone help me show these in my `ListView`?

Here is my `showProgressDialog`:

```
private void showProgressDialog(final String id, String title, String description, String property, String maintenanceTitle) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.archive_maintenance, null);

        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final Spinner spinnerProgress = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerProgress);
        final Button buttonUpdateProgress = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateProgress);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Maintenance: " + maintenanceTitle);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        buttonUpdateProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
                String desc = editTextDesc.getText().toString().trim();

                String progress = spinnerProgress.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String property = spinnerProperty.getSelectedItem().toString();

                updateProgress(title, desc, id, property, progress);

                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

And my `updateProgress` method:

```
private boolean updateProgress (String title, String desc, String id, String property, String progress) {

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("maintenance");
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

        params.put("progress", progress);

        databaseReference.child(uid)
                .child(id)
                .updateChildren(params);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Maintenance Updated Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
```

As you can see from my data structure, the node `progess` has changed to complete, but it is the `maintenanceProgress` that needs to be done.  The `progress` is changed by a `Spinner` and then an OK `Button`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add code on how you get data for you `ListView`?

Comment: yes add Your Code how you get that data from `Firebase`.